# WordPress/waypoints.js Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming, jquery-waypoints

Using WP 4.1, custom js

```
var waypoints = $('#about').waypoint({
  handler: function(direction) {
    console.log(this.element.id + ' hit')
  }
})
```

Getting this error in my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocationjquery.waypoints.min.js?ver=3.0.1:7
(anonymous function)jquery.js?ver=1.11.1:3 m.event.dispatchjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:3 r.handle
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Waypoints, with a [fix open](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/pull/366) that will be merged soon. The error stems from the fact that [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) must be called with `window` as the context.

**Update**: That fix has landed in `3.1.0`.